# JSP: Add background image for Input type ="submit"

Tags: jsp

I get some data from database into a list and then I want to show them in a table. My jsp code like this:

```
<table id = "main-table">
    <%
        DBConnector connector = new DBConnector();
        ArrayList<Book> list = new ArrayList<Book>();
        list = connector.GetData("0");
        int row = (int)Math.ceil(list.size()/5);
        int col = 5;

        for(int i = 0; i< row; i++){
    %>  
        <tr>
            <%
                for(int j = 0; j< col; j++){
            %>
                <td>
                    <form action = "BookDetail" method="get">
                        <input type ="submit" class = "thumbnailimg" name="<%=list.get(i*5+j).getName()%>"
                        style="background-image:url('<%= list.get(i*5+j).getImg()%>')"/>
                    </form>
                </td>
            <%
                }
            %>
        </tr>   
    <%
        }
    %>
```

I set background for each input with a link to a picture. But when I test, my table show inputs with default style and have no picture background.

Thank you.

Comment: are you sure `list.get(i*5+j).getImg()` returns a valid path to the image?

Comment: Yes, I test  with `<input name="<%= list.get(i*5+j).getName()%>" type="image" value="<%= list.get(i*5+j).getName()%>" src="<%= list.get(i*5+j).getImg()%>"/>` and I can see images

Comment: try  style="background: ...image.... no-repeat;"

Comment: sorry @MaVRoSCy, path to images in my database is wrong, there was a " symbol after each link. But I don't know why it works with image type input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it :D

```
<form action="BookDetail" method="get">
      <input type ="submit" class = "thumbnailimg" name="<%= list.get(i*5+j).getName()%>"
       style=" background-image: url('<%= list.get(i*5+j).getImg() %>'); width: 146px; height: 226px;"/>
</form>
```

well, I set width and height of `.thumbnail` in css file but it doesn't work.and in .css file:

```
.thumbnailimg{
border: 0;
color:transparent;
background-color:transparent;
cursor: pointer; 
cursor: hand;
outline:none;
}
```

well, I set width and height properties of `.thumbnail` in css file but it doesn't work.